# Flex HTTPService Error

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, httpservice

I am creating a Flex application and am using an HTTPService to retrieve XML from an asmx web service.  This web service needs one string parameter.  This parameter contains multiple options separated by ~ and parsed apart.  This web service works with a limited length of string, otherwise an error is retrieved if the string is long enough and no xml is retrieved.  However if the web service call is plugged directly into IE, the proper xml is retrieved.

The error:

faultCode:Server.Error.Request faultString:'HTTP request error' faultDetail:'Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error.

I believe the problem is a timeout issue but am unsure how to resolve this.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It actually appears to only be an issue with IE.  Everything works fine with Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a timeout error, you can set the `requestTimeout` property on your HTTPService object to `0` to prevent a timeout.

However, from your description I don't think a timeout is the issue. Could you post your code or sample code to demonstrate the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have set the contentType and method properties appropriately. if string lenght is the issue then try to use POST instead of GET